# GIT - Updating My Remote Repository

Tags: git

I am trying to upload a folder called 'repo' to a remote repository on a server.

I wrote on the server side:

```
mkdir -p ~/git/
git init --bare ~/git/repo.git
```

and on the local side:

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git remote add origin ssh://SERVER/~MYUSER/git/repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

What I got is the following when commit:

```
 create mode 100644 repo.zip
 create mode 100755 repo/clock.h
 create mode 100755 repo/conf/ips
 create mode 100755 repo/conf/msg
 create mode 100755 repo/conf/prt
 create mode 100755 repo/conf/tim
 create mode 100755 repo/conversions.h
 create mode 100755 repo/main.cpp
 create mode 100755 repo/message.h
 create mode 100755 repo/process.h
 create mode 100755 repo/view.h
```

and the following message after the push:

```
Counting objects: 15, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 11.3 KiB, done.
Total 15 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://SERVER/~MYUSER/git/repo.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

when I tried I tried to pull using:

```
git pull repo master
```

and I got:

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 15, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 15 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (15/15), done.
From repo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 repo.zip           |  Bin 0 -> 6838 bytes
 repo/clock.h       |    4 +
 repo/conf/ips      |    2 +
 repo/conf/msg      |    1 +
 repo/conf/prt      |    1 +
 repo/conf/tim      |    1 +
 repo/conversions.h |   89 ++++++++++++++++++
 repo/main.cpp      |  266 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 repo/message.h     |   51 ++++++++++
 repo/process.h     |   46 +++++++++
 repo/view.h        |   68 ++++++++++++++
 11 files changed, 529 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 repo.zip
 create mode 100755 repo/clock.h
 create mode 100755 repo/conf/ips
 create mode 100755 repo/conf/msg
 create mode 100755 repo/conf/prt
 create mode 100755 repo/conf/tim
 create mode 100755 repo/conversions.h
 create mode 100755 repo/main.cpp
 create mode 100755 repo/message.h
 create mode 100755 repo/process.h
 create mode 100755 repo/view.h
```

My problem is: Nothing is updated on the server.
Does any one has a clue what is going on?

Comment: i think u need to do a pull on your server

Comment: no, you don't pull on the server, it has no knowledge of the local repo, and it's bare, so that is the worst thing you could do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just replicated your setup and it seems to be working.

Try doing following from a different place:

```
git clone ssh://SERVER/~MYUSER/git/repo.git new-repo
cd new-repo
ls -l
```

now you'll see your files.

I think you may be getting confused or don't understand the difference between a bare repository and the working directory. You won't see any files in the server repository, as it's bare (so everything is in repository files), and there's no file system checked out there (working directory). You only get a working directory when you clone from a repository.

edit: go read some basic tutorials on [git working directories](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#Git-Generally-Only-Adds-Data)

Comment: Cloning into 'new_repo'...
remote: Counting objects: 15, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 15 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (15/15), 11.53 KiB, done.

then "cd new_repo"
I found my files :D

Do that mean that my folders are already located on the server but I can't found it ???!!!!

Comment: a "bare" repo is like a database holding your repository information, you won't find the directories as all the information is in data files. When you clone a repo from a bare repository you create a local copy of the repository (the .git dir) and a "working directory" which is the checked out version of it (the files and dirs you work on). Go and read up on working directory, e.g. http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#Git-Generally-Only-Adds-Data

Comment: Thank you very much. As you said, I thought that I should find regular files uploaded to the server. I deduced after pulling files that bare repos don't store files but it stores data rather.